# API: Is it correct to send back UI position related data in API response to the web/app clients?

Tags: rest, api, api-design

I am developing a classified automobile valuation API that would return value of used cars.

Sample API request:

```
{
  "car": "BMW X3 sportline",
  "milesDriven": 20000,
  "yearOfPurchase": 2010,
  "askingPrice": "₹₹₹$20000"
}
```

The request sends car details with the price what seller expects.

Sample API response:

```
{
  "badConditionPrice": "₹₹₹$30000",
  "goodConditionPrice": "₹₹₹$35000"
}
```

The response sends back 2 prices to indicate rough estimate for ideal price the car should be sold at.

Now, at each client(web/app) we have to show all 3 prices - "askingPrice", "badConditionPrice", "goodConditionPrice".

While "badConditionPrice", "goodConditionPrice" has fixed position ["bad" at left and "good" at right], the position of "askingPrice" will vary. For example:

1. If asking price is less than "badConditionPrice", it would be shown to left of "badConditionPrice" and "goodConditionPrice".
2. If asking price is greater than "badConditionPrice" but less than "goodConditionPrice", it would be in middle.
3. If asking price is greater than "goodConditionPrice" , it would be to the right of "goodConditionPrice".

My question is- who should decide the exact position of "askingPrice" - CLIENT or SERVER?

In case its server we need to send back flag to indicate its position OR if its client, we need to write this logic at each client.

Comment: This is rather opinionated and depends on your design. I'd opt for positioning is client dependent. The service should return only information, how the client presents these information to the user is its thing. One client may position an image according the price, an other might only color things from green to orange to red or similar.

Comment: @RomanVaottner: Assuming all client position it in the same manner, what should be the choice?

Comment: are you just looking for arguments to shift presentation state from clients to the service? If so, than you already have your solution and the post is rather useless

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how you position your data and your preference. What is easier and requires you to jump fewer places to change later on if you have to?